# Is there any design pattern for perfect forwarding when the function may fail and need the caller to retry?

Tags: c++, c++11

My question is regarding to perfect forwarding, let's see the example first,

```
template<typename A, typename B>
void foo(A &&a, B &&b) {
   A internal_a = std::forward<A>(a);
   B internal_b = std::forward<B>(b);
}
```

So far so good. I can call it like this,

```
X x;
Y y;
// do a lot of stuff on x, y
//.....
//.....
// we will use x,y in foo(x, y) only, so we can just move
foo(std::move(x), std::move(y));
```

Now, say foo may fail.

```
template<typename A, typename B>
bool foo(A &&a, B &&b) {
   A internal_a = std::forward<A>(a);
   B internal_b = std::forward<B>(b);
   // ...
   if (xxx) {
       return false;
   }
   // ...
   return true;
}
```

In the caller,

```
X x;
Y y;
// do a lot of stuff on x, y
//.....
//.....
// Oh my!
while (!foo(std::move(x), std::move(y)) ;
```

This wont work because the first call to foo will move x and y.

If the caller does not use move, then we lose all the advantages of move.

We can do this:

```
X x;
Y y;
do {
   // do a lot of stuff on x, y
   //.....
   //.....
}
while (!foo(std::move(x), std::move(y)) ;
```

This makes the caller very troublesome.

We can also possibly do this,

```
template<typename A, typename B>
bool foo(A &&a, B &&b) {
   A internal_a = std::forward<A>(a);
   B internal_b = std::forward<B>(b);
   // ...
   if (xxx) {
       // This may move or copy, where the copy is uncessary
       a = std::forward<A>(internal_a);
       b = std::forward<B>(internal_b);
       return false;
   }
   // ...
   return true;
}
```

This may work well if it is indeed move in the caller. If the caller does not move, this involves unnecessary copies.

Probably what I need is to know exactly move or copy occurs inside the perfect forwarding, and if it is move, we must move the back to make the caller easier.

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: In situations like this, the simplest solution is just not to move anything. Pass a single reference to the stuff that the function needs, packed into a struct or a class. The function accesses everything by digging into the struct. If the function needs to be called again, pass the same reference again. Everything is there just where you left it, perfectly preserved. Just because C++ now has "perfect forwarding" doesn't mean that it has to be used every time, just for the benefit of using it.

Comment: Well, the first thing I see is that you maybe don't want to move until you see that your condition is satisfied. Another way is that I think you _technically_ could move the variables back, as you would be initializing an (now uninitialized object, after the move from it) from your temporary.

Comment: If the function `foo` has modified its local variables, what good is it to move them back to the caller's arguments? If it hasn't modified them, why did it need those local variables at all before that point?

Comment: @aschepler In my use case, the local variable is not really "local", it is a memory store for fast data retrieval. The data store might be accessed via multiple-threads (both reading and writing). It makes sense to firstly insert the data into some temporary structure (have to move or copy), but later found that the structure conflicts with other threads and have to announce failure of insertion (the structure has to be deleted). In this case the caller has to try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the strong exception guarantee extended to a return type instead of an exception exit path.

The idea is that, on failure, everything is returned back to the initial state.

Not that the inverse of forward is not forward back; the inverse of copy is noop not copy.  Admittedly the inverse of move is move-back.  You'd use something different, like a transacrion-rollback system, not a forward in the opposite direction.  And doing it manually is bad; use RAII.  Finally, you'll want to consider exceptions and how to deal with throwing move operations.

What you want is really hard without noexcept or transactional memory.

Answer (score 0):

According to all the comments, write a RAII is probably the best solution. I post what I wrote (may not cater all situations), please comment if somewhere is wrong.

```
template<typename A, typename B>
class move_guard {
private:
    bool release_;
    A a_;
    B b_;

    template<typename A_, typename B_>
    void move_internal_(A_ &a, B_ &&b) {
        a = std::move(b);
    }
    template<typename A_, typename B_>
    void move_internal_(const A_ &a, B_ &&b) {
    }

public:
    explicit move_guard(A a, B b, bool release) : a_(static_cast<A>(a)), b_(b), release_(release) {}
    move_guard(const move_guard &other) = delete;
    move_guard(move_guard &&other) : a_(static_cast<A>(other.a_)), b_(other.b_), release_(other.release_) {
        other.release_ = true;
    }
    move_guard &operator=(const move_guard&) = delete;
    move_guard &operator=(move_guard &&other) = delete;
    void release() { release_ = true; }

    ~move_guard() { 
        if (!release_) {
            // cannot just a_ = std::move(b_) because a_ might be const
            // lvalue ref, we cant pass the compilation although in runtime
            // it never will be called if a_ is const. 
            move_internal_(a_, b_);
        }
    }
};



// If a is an rvalue ref, return a guard that will move b back to a before destroyed.
// If a is a const-rvalue-ref, something is wrong, we don't allow this.
// If a is an lvalue ref (const or non-const), return a guard that does nothing.
template<typename A, typename B>
auto make_move_guard(A &&a, B &&b) {
    typedef decltype(a) atype;
    typedef decltype(b) btype;
    typedef typename std::remove_reference<atype>::type a_noref_type;
    typedef typename std::remove_reference<btype>::type b_noref_type;
    typedef typename std::remove_const<a_noref_type>::type a_base_type;
    typedef typename std::remove_const<b_noref_type>::type b_base_type;

    static_assert( !(std::is_rvalue_reference<atype>::value && std::is_const<a_noref_type>::value), 
        "It is non-sense to allow a to be a const-rvalue-reference.");
    static_assert(std::is_same<a_base_type, b_base_type>::value, 
        "The arguments must have the same base type.");
    static_assert(!std::is_rvalue_reference<btype>::value,
        "It is non-sense to allow b to be an rvalue-reference.");

    if (std::is_rvalue_reference<atype>::value) {
        return move_guard<atype &&, b_noref_type &>(std::forward<A>(a), b, false);
    } else {
        return move_guard<atype &&, b_noref_type &>(std::forward<A>(a), b, true);
    }
}

template<typename A, typename B>
bool foo(A &&a, B &&b) {
   A internal_a = std::forward<A>(a);
   B internal_b = std::forward<B>(b);

   auto guard_a = make_move_guard(std::forward<A>(a), internal_a);
   auto guard_b = make_move_guard(std::forward<B>(b), internal_b);

   if (xxx)
       return false;

   //if everything all right
   guard_a.release();
   guard_b.release();
   return true;
}
```